# How to display char fields in a pivot table in Odoo?

Tags: xml, graph, odoo, nvd3.js

I'm building an odoo module; and I have the following fields:

```
 1- status: integer

 2- Description: char
```

I'd like to display the two fields in a pivot format, so here is the xml code for the view:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="id_view_causedisfonctionnement_automate_minoterie">
    <field name="name">mymodule.graph</field>
    <field name="model">mymodule</field>
    <field name="type">graph</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <graph string="mymodule" type="pivot" >
             <field name="status" interval="seconds" type="col"/>
             <field name="description"  type="col" />
        </graph>
    </field>
</record>
```

But the problem is that in the pivot table there is no values of the description (this code display an empty table), however there is data in the database.

Could any one help me?